# Pygame sprite file error

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Disclaimer: I'm only 10 years old so please be patient with me please :D

So I'm working on this game in pygame where you play as a balloon and you have to avoid obstacles and collect points. The points add 10 to your score and the obstacles restart your game. You use the arrow keys to move. It's based off Ski-Free. But whenever I run it I don't get an error in my script, but an error in the sprite.py file that pygame comes with. For info, I use Mac OSX Sierra as my OS and IDLE 2.712 as my shell. I use python 2. So, here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/------------/Desktop/Sky Balloon.py", line 75, in <module>
create_map()
  File "/Users/------------/Desktop/Sky Balloon.py", line 58, in create_map
    obstacles.add(obstacles)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 142, in add
self.add(*group)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be an iterable, not ObstacleClass
```

P.S. I did cover up my but the number of characters is still the same.
Now here's my actual game script. (Sky Balloon.py)

```
import pygame, sys, random
baloon_images = ["Baloon_gif.gif", "pop.gif"]

class BaloonClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):f
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.image.load("Baloon_gif.gif")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = [320, 100]
    self.angle = 0


def turn(self, direction):
    self.angle = self.angle + direction
    if self.angle < -2: self.angle = -2
    if self.angle > 2: self.angle = 2
    center = self.rect.center
    self.image = pygame.image.load(baloon_images[self.angle])
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = center
    speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) * 2]
    return speed

def move(self, speed):
   self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + speed[0]
   if self.rect.centerx < 20: self.rect.centerx = 20
   if self.rect.centerx > 620: self.rect.centerx = 620


class ObstacleClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, type):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_file = image_file
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = location
        self.type = type
        self.passed = False
def update(self):
        global speed
        self.rect.centery -= speed[1]
        if self.rect.centery < -32:
            self.kill()
def create_map():
global obstacles
locations = []
for i in range(10):
    row = random.randint(0, 9)
    col = random.randint(0, 9)
    location = [col * 64 + 20, row * 64 + 20 + 640]
    if not (location in locations):
        locations.append(location)
        type = random.choice(["cloud", "point"])
        if type == "cloud": img = "cloud.png"
        elif type == "point": img = "Points.png"
        obstacles = ObstacleClass(img, location, type)
        obstacles.add(obstacles)

def animate():
    screen.fill([0, 255, 255])
    obstacles.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(baloon.image, baloon.rect)
    screen.blit(score_text, [10, 10])
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 640])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
baloon = BaloonClass()
speed = [0, 6]
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
map_position = 0
points = 0
create_map()
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    speed = baloon.turn(-1)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = baloon.turn(1)
baloon.move(speed)

map_position += speed[1]

if map_position >=640:
      create_map()
      map_position = 0

hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(baloon, obstacles, False)
if hit:
      if hit[0].type == "cloud" and not hit[0].passed:
          points = points - 100
          baloon.image = pygame.image.load("pop.gif")
          animate()
          pygame.time.delay(1000)
          baloon.image = pygame.image.load("Baloon_gif.gif")
          baloon.angle = 0
          speed = [0, 6]
          hit[0].passed = True
elif hit[0].type == "point" and not hit[0].passed:
          points += 10
          hit[0].kill()

obstacles.update()
score_text = font.render("Score: " +str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))
animate()
pygame.quit
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

`obstacles.add(obstacle)` not `obstacles.add(obstacles)` (extra s)

Comment: Should probably just flag this for typo

Comment: @pvg: It's the cause of the problem, though. Not a random comment.

Comment: It's not about whether it is or isn't the cause. Questions that turn out to be about typos are off-topic because they can't possibly ever help anyone else.  Comment to help the poster and flag it.

Comment: I agree with @pvg, just comment explaining the typo and flag it as off-topic. From the [on-topic guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the following questions are off topic: "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or that was caused by a simple typographical error.** While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Comment: Well, now there's a new error on that line. It says global name "obstacle" is not defined. Do I have some sort of indentation error? I had a lot of those while troubleshooting. Keep in mind that I can run my script and it opens pygame but then the terminal gets an error and pygame is stuck on this endless loading screen.

Comment: Previous line as well...
 `obstacle = ObstacleClass(img, location, type)`
 `obstacles.add(obstacle)`

Comment: OK, I'll also try that.

Comment: Gonna assume this is another typo, but now my error says THIS and I really don't understand it. Again, name is censored `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/------------/Desktop/Sky Balloon.py", line 102, in <module>
    animate()
  File "/Users/------------/Desktop/Sky Balloon.py", line 64, in animate
    screen.blit(score_text, [10, 10])
NameError: global name 'score_text' is not defined`